# Logstash creates enormous local log files and (although it sends then to Elasticsearch)

Tags: configuration, logstash, elastic-stack, local-files

## The problem

I have a machine with logstash on it, and another Elasticsearch-Kibana machine which stores the logs written from logstash on the first machine. Naturally, I want no logs to be kept on the origin machine and handle logging only on the Elasticsearch cluster.

Unfortunately, logstash creates huge log files on the first machine (where nothing should be kept):

[image]

## The configuration

I have only one file under `/etc/logstash` on the origin machine, and as far as I can see, the configuration does not specify a local output:

```ruby
input {
        tcp {
                port => 5959
                codec => json
        }
        udp {
                port => 5959
        }
}
filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
}
filter{
        if [@message] == "Incoming Event" {
            mutate{
                    add_field => {
                              "location" =>  "%{@fields[location]}"
                        }
                }
        }
}
output {
        elasticsearch {
                # The host in which elasticsearch and Kibana live
                host => "some.internal.aws.ip" 
        }
}
```

**How can I stop logstash from writing local logs by configuration? I know I can cron-del them, but I think that prevention is less error-prone.**

Comment: Do you have verbose or debug enabled on your logstash?  Disabling those would cut down on the volume.  To completely eliminate them, I'd edit your startup script, but having them is a good idea...

Comment: Where are these defined?

Comment: There are --debug and --verbose command line options to logstash.  They might appear in your startup script, or in a config file read by your startup script (sysconfig, etc).

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as you running on a CentOS 7 machine. No output to anything else than elasticsearch but logstash still output all the incoming messages to `logstash.log` and `logstash.stdout`

After a bit of research of the actual ruby-code it turned out that the default logging mode is very verbose.

There is however a flag (seems to be undocumented as far as I can see) called `--quiet` which solves the problem.

Add the flag to the `LS_OPTS`-variable either in the config file (`/etc/sysconfig/logstash` on centos) or directly in the `init.d` script like so:

```
# Arguments to pass to logstash agent
LS_OPTS="--quiet"
```

Comment: on windows this seems to be located here: "\logstash\config\startup.options"

Answer (score 6):

This output is likely caused by having the following in one of your output config files:

```
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

After removing that from my `30-output.conf` logstash stopped being so verbose

[This thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-stdout-large-size/24939/4) led me to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## The logrotate solution

Unfortunately, I did not find any `--verbose` or `--debug` flags in `/etc/init.d/logstash`. Therefore, I tried to figure out why `logrotate` was not archiving the file.

`/etc/logrotate.d/logstash` is:

```
/var/log/logstash/*.log {
        daily
        rotate 7
        copytruncate
        compress
        delaycompress
        missingok
        notifempty
}
```

But when I tried running it, I got:

```
$ logrotate --force logrotate.d/logstash --verbose
Ignoring logrotate.d/logstash because of bad file mode.
```

A [quick search came to the rescue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3490):

```
sudo chmod 0644 logrotate.d/logstash
```

I have changed the frequency from `daily` to `hourly` and everything seems to work fine now.

This should probably not be the accepted answer. If anyone has a better solution which can prevent logstash from writing these redundant logs in the first place, I would love to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the docker image, logstash ships it with a default pipeline named `logstash (logstash.conf)`. That pipeline logs everything to stdout. You MUST override it to avoid imense logs